# Which is the difference in assigning a variable and working directly in array,in IPython

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython

I'm playing around with IPython and remote control:

```
in:  from IPython Import parallel as p
in:  rc=p.client(profile=myprofile)
```

There is a behavior difference between

```
in:  rc[0].block
out: False
in:  rc[0].block=True
in:  rc[0].block
out: False
```

and

```
in:  view=rc[0]
in:  view.block
out: False
in:  view.block=True
in:  view.block
out: True
```

I realy can't understand what append ? Why is that ? what do assignement do ?

Comment: Looks like __getitem__ returns direct_view(key) which invoques Direct_View which have 'parallelmagic' in its source. I gess i'll never understand by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment itself does nothing. `rc` here is your client. Doing `rc[0]`, or any sort of indexing, generates and returns a DirectView object that's a view with whatever engines you specify in []. This is a shorthand for generating the views: it's not actually just getting a specific object.

Thus, those views aren't unique. The best way to explain it, I think, is with an example. Say you have 2 engines. You want to run some tasks on only engine one, and want the tasks to block. You want to run others on only engine one, but don't want them to block. You want to run yet more on engines 1 and 2, and don't want them to block. Then you could do:

```
view_1_block = rc[0]
view_1_block.block = True
view_2_noblock = rc[0]
view_2_noblock.block = False
view_3_noblock = rc[[0,1]]
view_3_noblock.block = False
```

Then, you can use these to run tasks in whatever way you'd like, eg

```
view_1_block.map(lambda x:x**10, range(32)) # blocks, returns results, runs only on 1
view_3_noblock.map(lambda x:x**10, range(32)) # does not block, returns AsyncResult, runs on 1 and 2
```

There's no actual magic being used here. When you run rc[0] twice, it generates two views. The second view is not the same as the first. When you assign rc[0] to a variable, and then use that variable, you're working with one view, and not creating a new one.

iPython, like Numpy and Scipy, has quite a few shorthand notations that don't necessarily fit Python's idioms perfectly. This is especially the case with [] and getitem. A purer Python way of writing this could would be to use the much more unwieldy `rc.direct_view(1)`, and so on, which would make clear that this wasn't just getting an item, and was actually creating a view.